# Arguments of function?

Tags: python, function

I am learning to program, and I had a question regarding the functions.
Basically because I should use arguments in functions if I can get all the result by doing everything in the function. What are the benefits? Is it good practice?

**Sorry if the question is very basic.**

Here an example using python:

```
num1,num2 = 2,3

def sum(a,b):
    z= a+b
    print(z)

sum(num1,num2)
```

```
def sum():
    a,b = 2,3
    z= a+b
    print(z)

sum()
```

In theory, both functions do the same, but in which cases is it advisable to use arguments or not?

Comment: Let's say you want to sum two other numbers in another part of the code. Which options seems best then?

Comment: @hansolo I understand, the same concept applies if my variables in the second function were an input?

Comment: I think you're talking about *parameters*, not arguments per se. See the FAQ: [What is the difference between arguments and parameters?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-is-the-difference-between-arguments-and-parameters)

Comment: Sidenote: [`sum` is a builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), so to avoid [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) it, you should use a different name, like `add` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to be calling the function just once, we could say there is not benefit from it. Now, let's say you want to perform the same operation multiple times, but with different input data. Then, you see the improvement:

```py
def sum(a, b):
    z = a + b
    print(z)

sum(1, 2)
sum(2, 3)
sum(4, 5)
```

would be better than:

```py
z = 1 + 2
print(z)
z = 2 + 3
print(z)
z = 4 + 5
print(z)
```

Comment: I understand, the same concept applies if my variables in the second function were an input?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. If, in the second case, you had `a` and `b` as parameters (function input), then your function would be the same as in the first case.

Comment: So in that case, what would be the difference between use arg or not

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the application of use. If it needs some dynamic content like in the first case

```
num1,num2 = 2,3

def sum(a,b):
    z= a+b
    print(z)

sum(num1,num2)
```

but if it is some basic content,
use the second one.

```
def sum():
    a,b = 2,3
    z= a+b
    print(z)

sum()
```

Comment: I understand, the same concept applies if my variables in the second function were an input?

Comment: @carlosm, yes. I assume by input you mean the input() function. But it should only be used if you want user input.

Comment: @carlosm , the second function can only add 2 and 3. but the first function can add multiple values.

Comment: @SayanDasgupta yeah I know i understand the concept, but if I use the function input(), what will be the difference assuming that the global variables for the first are inputs, and for the second case the variables in this case local, what would be the difference between one and the other for that case,I mean the concept will be the same?

Comment: @carlosm yes, the concept is basically the same. To use the local variable specifically use `this` keyword and if you want to use global its ok, in python.

Answer (score 1):

The main benefit of adding arguments to a function is that you can use the function multiple times with different arguments every time.
This can be very practical when you are building a calculator program, for example, and want to be able to find the sum of *any* two numbers not only of specific ones.

p.s.: If you want to use the functionality of your function only once, maybe you should consider not using a function at all (unless you need to find the sum of specific numbers a few times, in which case, as said, you wouldn't use arguments)